# I need help setup a controller test using Spring, Junit 5, Mockito, REST-Assured, and Lombok

Tags: spring, mockito, junit5, rest-assured

I need help setting up a controller test using Spring, Junit 5, Mockito, REST-Assured, and Lombok.

Have I missed a configuration step?

When I try to run a test, I am getting:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getMockitoLogger()Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockitoLogger;

In UserController.java @Slf4j via Lombok is used to setup logging, and has some log.info("Some Log text") statements.

UserControllerTest.java

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserControllerTest extends TestAbstract {
    private final static String URI = "/user";

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;
    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;
    @InjectMocks
    private ControllerExceptionHandler controllerExceptionHandler;

    @BeforeEach
    public void initialiseRestAssuredMockMvcStandalone() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(userController, controllerExceptionHandler);
    }
...
}
```

Maven Pom:

```
...
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit-jupiter.version> <!--junit 5-->
        <mockito-junit-jupiter.version>3.4.3</mockito-junit-jupiter.version> <!--mockito for junit 5--> 
        <!--mockito ver 3.5.13 also attempted-->
        <spring-mock-mvc.version>3.3.0</spring-mock-mvc.version> <!--rest-assured-->
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
...
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-mock-mvc.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
...
```

**Update/Correction**

Correction: `@Before` in UserControllerTest.java has been corrected to `@BeforeEach` as is correct for junit 5.

Update: The use of Spring requires a careful use of imports, as noted in the [REST-Assured docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#bootstrapping-restassuredmockmvc).

You should use:

```
import static io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc.*
import static io.restassured.module.mockmvc.matcher.RestAssuredMockMvcMatchers.*
```

And avoid using:

```
io.restassured.RestAssured.*
io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*
```

As near as I can tell there is not error to tell you, that you are using the wrong import.

**Correction**
Correction: REST-Assured version to 3.3.0. Later version do not work with Java 8.

Comment: Take a look at `@WebMvcTest` , see here for examples : https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-web-controller-test/

Comment: You might want to add `@SpringBootTest` to your class. This will start a springboot test context.

Comment: @akuma8 `@WebMvcTest` is an alternative to rest-assured. Here I am trying to use rest-assured, which created its own MockMvc. Using both creates a 'No application context loaded' error.

Comment: @tgr Adding '@SpringBootTest` has no effect. I get the same error.

Comment: I am curious to know how you planned to test a controller without providing a minimal web context, which  `@WebMvcTest` provides.

Comment: @akuma8 I am not doing an integration test. yet. The `@Before` here allows me to isolate just the controller and test it. When I need for an integration test there is a `initialiseRestAssuredMockMvcWebApplicationContext()` instead of the standalone.

Comment: Step 5 in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-mvc-rest-assured show exactly what I am trying to do, but with junit4.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround for the controller test issue. Step back to junit 4 for the controller test. My dependencies do not change as junit 4 is accessible inside junit 5.

Interestingly, I found I can use the same REST-Assured code for both my integration tests and the controller tests. The only difference is the the controller tests mocks the service layer. Thus I have an abstract parent class, UserControllerTestAbstract.java, with two children, UserControllerTest.java and UserIntegrationTest.java.

UserControllerTestAbstract.java (junit 5)

```
...
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;  // junit 5

import static io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc.given;
...

public abstract class UserControllerTestAbstract extends UserTestAbstract implements ControllerTestAbstract {
... // protected static final User variables ... for testing

    @Tag("positive")
    @Test
    public void whenAddUser_thenReturnsSuccessfulDefaultResponse() {
        // given a AddUserRequest
        AddUserRequest testAddUserRequest = AddUserRequest.builder()
                .user(testNewUser)
                .build();

        DefaultResponse foundDefaultResponse = given().log().all()
                .spec(requestSpec)
                .body(testAddUserRequest)

        // when addUser returns a Successful DefaultResponse
            .when()
                .post("/add")

        // then the JSON response is as expected
            .then().log().all()
                .spec(responseSpec)
                .extract().as(DefaultResponse.class);
        assertSuccessfulStatus(foundDefaultResponse); // custom assert method
    }
...
}
```

When I try to run the test in the abstract class, IntelliJ will ask me which child class to use.

The ControllerTestAbstract interface is another abstraction layer that defines the requestSpec and responseSpec variables.

UserIntegrationTest.java (junit 5)

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; // junit 5
...

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@Tag("integration-test")
public class UserIntegrationTest extends UserControllerTestAbstract {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @BeforeEach  // junit 5
    public void initialiseRestAssuredMockMvcWebApplicationContext() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.basePath = "/user";
    }

    // The tests are in UserControllerTestAbstract and are used in the controller test as well.

    @Tag("negative")
    @Test
    @Disabled
    public void whenGetListOfAllUsers_thenReturnsErrorUserListResponse() {
        // This overrides and disables this integration test.
        // The test fails, because data.sql adds users to the DB.
        // To run this test, comment out all inserts to the users table in data.sql in both test and main resources.
        // Alternatively, you could rename data.sql in both test and main resources.
        // Then comment out @Disabled
        super.whenGetListOfAllUsers_thenReturnsErrorUserListResponse();
    }
}
```

So far only one test needed to be overridden and disable, because it needed a table to be empty to generate a correct response. Many of the other tests expected that table to be populated.

UserControllerTest.java (junit 4)

```
import org.junit.Test; // junit 4
...

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)  // junit 4
@Tag("controller")
@Tag("unit-test")
public class UserControllerTest extends UserControllerTestAbstract {

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;
    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;
    @InjectMocks
    private ControllerExceptionHandler controllerExceptionHandler;

    @Before // junit 4
    public void initialiseRestAssuredMockMvcStandalone() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(userController, controllerExceptionHandler);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.basePath = "/user";
    }

    @Tag("positive")
    @Test
    public void whenAddUser_thenReturnsSuccessfulDefaultResponse() {
        // given a User, a AddUserRequest and a DefaultResponse
        AddUserRequest testAddUserRequest = AddUserRequest.builder()
                .user(testNewUser)
                .build();
        DefaultResponse testDefaultResponse = new DefaultResponse();

        // when addUser returns a Successful DefaultResponse
        given(userService.addUser(any(AddUserRequest.class))).willReturn(testDefaultResponse);

        // then the JSON response is as expected
        super.whenAddUser_thenReturnsSuccessfulDefaultResponse();
    }
...
}
```